# Reference for convex optimization

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$ be compact and convex
and
suppose that $f:E \to\mathbb{R}$ is strictly convex (jointly in all of its arguments). Consider the following minimization procedure: an initial $(x_0,y_0)\in E$ is picked arbitrarily, then $x_1$ is defined as the (unique) minimizer of $f(\cdot,y_0)$, then $y_1$ is the minimizer of $f(x_1,\cdot)$ and so on. It's fairly obvious and not hard to show that this process converges to the unique minimum of $f$. What I need is a standard reference for this fact.
[Edit: Not true! Some stronger smoothness condition is needed, such as strong convexity and twice-differentiability. See Theo Bendit's answer and comment.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, such a reference doesn't exist, because the result isn't true.

The method you're describing is known as "coordinate descent". In the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent), there is an example showing how coordinate descent can fail when the function is not continuously differentiable. While this example is not strictly convex (and doesn't have compact domain, but this is trivial to fix), we can modify it to form a counterexample.

Let $f(x, y) = |x + y| + 3|x - y| + (x + 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2$. Essentially, this is the counterexample from the wiki page, with the strictly convex function $(x + 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2$ added to it, to make the whole function strictly convex. As with the counterexample on the wiki, if you begin at $(-2, -2)$, and perform coordinate descent, you find that both coordinates achieve their minimum at $(-2, -2)$; the sum of the paraboloid with global minimum at $(-2, -2)$ will not change this fact.

What it will change is where the global minimum of this function lies. Without bothering to prove it, we can just observe that
$$f(-2, -2) = 4 > 3.5 = f(-1.5, -1.5),$$
so performing coordinate descent on this function will not get you to the global minimum, despite being strictly convex.

Comment: Many thanks -- indeed, an embarrassing blunder. What if we add continuous differentiability as an additional hypothesis?

Comment: I had a poke through Wikipedia's references. I can't find anything so clean as to say continuous differentiability suffices. The referenced paper by [Luo and Tseng](https://hdl.handle.net/1721.1%2F3164) (1992) show that convergence occurs with strong convexity and twice-differentiability (see Theorem on page $6$, and the remark about standing assumptions directly above it).